# How to fix a load fixture error

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

I'm trying to import initial data into my Django application. I have several tables, but I'd like to import them one by one.

I decided to begin with the simplest table:

```
class ClientRun(models.Model):
    start_time = models.BigIntegerField()
    end_time = models.BigIntegerField()
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.start_time) + " " + str(self.end_time)
```

And I manually created a fixture file:

```
[
  {
    "model": "georoute.clientrun",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "ip": "0.0.0.0",
        "start_time": 0,
        "end_time": 0,
        "country": "ZZ"
    }
  },
]
```

When I run

```
python manage.py loaddata shengy_clientrun.json
```

it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 60, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 90, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 141, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 84, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 78, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 109, in Deserializer
    for (field_name, field_value) in six.iteritems(d["fields"]):
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/shengy/Dropbox/shengy/code/django_tutorial/gae_site/georoute/fixtures/shengy_clientrun.json': u'fields'
```

I double-checked the JSON format, and the database is now empty. I'm using MySQL as the backend database.

Comment: Your fixture is not valid JSON.  Unlike Python, JSON cannot have trailing commas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your fixture is not valid JSON. Unlike Python, JSON cannot have trailing commas.